# Angular - ng-change not firing when ng-model is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

The input is the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="repair.test"  ng-change="action()" />
```

The `action()` is executed when I manually type and change the input. However if I change the repair.test value by some other function programmatically, it doesnt fire the ng-change's action. I have read the angular tutorial and it's probably the expected behavior.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

"The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model." <- I need this too.
How can I fire an action in controller, when the model changes in any way? (typing in input or by any other function)

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

The model value is actually the `form.$valid`, which has it's own Form controller around it (I think), that is why I used the action function to try to pass the value to the parent controller. So `$scope.$watch` at the moment doesn't work, only when it is initialised.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) is just for the input, if you want to listen the model do like this

```
$scope.$watch('repair.test', function(newvalue,oldvalue) {

            });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this approach, the thing is, the value I actually need in controller is the form.$valid, which has its own Form controller. So basically I need to pass value from child controller to parent controller. That's the reason I used the action method, to try to pass value to controller. Any thoughts how I can do this?

Comment: I have reworked my code to use $scope.$watch, thank you.

Comment: ng-change should work for input type which is present in the main question. However i did not see any answer which tells why it did not work for ng-change? I too have the same issue. Thank you

Comment: This really helped me to understand why $watch is used, thank you!

Comment: It is working if I put the value in new controller. Why its so???

Comment: Check the values in the parameters, angular 1 did use the concept of "dirty checking" meaning that it can trigger this function even if the model is undefined (that's only a supposition as i haven't use angular 1 for years now)

Answer (score 8):

The [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

It will **not** be evaluated:

- if the value returned from the `$parsers` transformation pipeline has
  not changed
- if the input has continued to be invalid since the model
  will stay null
- **if the model is changed programmatically and not by a
  change to the input value**

Try to create a watcher using [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) - `$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`

Example

```
$scope.$watch('repair.test', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a watcher-function in your controller

```
$scope.$watch('repair.test', function() {
    $scope.action();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a directive that watched the model for any changes instead of using `ng-change`.

```js
app.directive('onModelChange', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "?ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (typeof(newValue) === "undefined" || newValue == oldValue) {
                    return;
                }
                var changeExpr = $parse(attrs['onModelChange']);
                if (changeExpr) {
                    changeExpr(scope);
                }
            });
        } 
    };
});
```

Then you would use it like so:

```html
<input class="value" type="text" ng-model="myVar" on-model-change="doSomething(myVar)"/>
```