# Angularjs bootstrap pagination set page is not triggering page change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angular-bootstrap

I have following pagination code

```
<pre>There are {{total_records}} number of records</pre>
<pagination ng-model="current_page"
            total-items="total_records"
            items-per-page="items_per_page"
            max-size="max_size" class="pagination-sm"
            boundary-links="true" rotate="false"
            num-pages="numPages" ng-change="pageChanged()">
</pagination>
```

When I change pagination by clicking on the DOM it works. But when I try to change the pagination by setting $scope.current_page within code it doesn't trigger pageChanged.

For example,

On DOM let's say I am at 3rd page ($scope.current_page is 3) and on DOM 3rd page is active.
If I go to page 4 by click on DOM then on DOM 4th page is got active, $scope.current changes to 4,  and pageChagned is triggered.

But

On DOM let's say I am at 3rd page ($scope.current_page is 3) and on DOM 3rd page is active.
If I go to page 4 by changing $scope.current_page to 4 in code then at DOM page change changes to 4 but pageChanged is not getting triggered.

How can I trigger pageChanged on changing $scope.current_page at code? I have seen another solution when they suggested to use $scope.$watch but I want to know better way of doing.

Edit:

I created following plnkr (I used this for first time, so not sure whether I have done correct or not).
http://plnkr.co/edit/Kldv7ZbexpgifiPIsjCT?p=preview

The problem you can see is that when you click on "Go to 3rd page" button "page number" doesn't change on `<pre></pre>` tags.

Thanks

Comment: can you show more js code ? Luckly I am working on pagination right now  may be you could help me too. :)

Comment: Created a plnkr and updated. I used plnkr for first time and hoping I have done correctly.

Comment: just add ($scope.number_of_change)++; in the setPage function ?? this will increment count of page change (i hope thats what you want ) everytime you click on that button to go to page 3

Comment: is this what you want ? http://plnkr.co/edit/jDODdXvrpZ9jfP2XG0jB?p=preview

Comment: That can be done but I was thinking that after changing current_page it should trigger page change. As I am already having one function for handling page change why should I repeat same code inside setPage().

Comment: I am honestly lost as to what you are trying to achieve. However from what I understood when you change $scope.currentpage to 4 then  on load it will start from page 4 (active). Later when you move forward/backward the page number change will increase as per code

Comment: No problem. Really appreciated your effort. Its not calling pageChanged() when $scope.current_page  changed in code. Thank you I will use the way you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

ng-change isn't triggered by code changes. You can get the desired effect by using $scope.$watch in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.current_page;
}, function() {
    $scope.number_of_change++;
});
```

[updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XyFH4TIsArGLejzh1EMe?p=info)

(Honestly, this is a duplicate of [Angular - ng-change not firing when ng-model is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802627/angular-ng-change-not-firing-when-ng-model-is-changed), which has a [more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802627/angular-ng-change-not-firing-when-ng-model-is-changed#answer-39452020), but I don't have enough reputation to flag this question.)