# Implementing ng-change With Angularjs Custome Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have Following Directive , how can i implement ng-change with it . the directive is working but ng-change only works when i manually change value of text box not when i change it using date picker

```
 app.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            $(function () {


                element.persianDatepicker({
                    formatDate: "YYYY/0M/0D",
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and in my HTML

```
 <input datepicker type="text" id="EndDate" ng-model="Filter.EndDate" class="form-control" ng-change="DateSelect()" />
```

DateSelect() only runs when i change value of text box manually

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

`ng-change` is directive only for user input. Try to use `$watch` instead. Here are good answers:

[Angular - ng-change not firing when ng-model is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802627/angular-ng-change-not-firing-when-ng-model-is-changed)

[When to use $watch or ng-change in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313865/when-to-use-watch-or-ng-change-in-angularjs)

Comment: didn't work , should i change anything in input tag ?

Comment: `element` in angular is Jquery object. Try to remove `$(function () {`

Comment: thanks for your answers , but i finally used bootstrap datepicker and i works , the problem is with jquery date picker because even with jquery event change binding , it doesnt do anything.